# How to change the Bluetooth PIN in a Motorola rs507 using Bluetooth or barcodes?

Tags: bluetooth, barcode, barcode-scanner, motorola, motorola-emdk

How can we set the rs507 Bluetooth pin that is given to our Bluetooth access point (pirani 1000) when the access point is connector mode?

Is it possible with printing one custom barcode that sets the pin? For example  ...

I tried the section xx in the guide where shows how to set a "variable pin" on the sr507 and followed the procedure but scanned 3 thrice and scanned the "end" barcode and I set the Bluetooth access point pin to 333 and enabled BT authentication and encryption on both devices.

The devices will only connect if we set both the rs507 pin and the Bluetooth ap (pirani) pin to 12345.

This leads me to believe we cant set the pin? Can we combine the whole procedure into one barcode?

Comment: 12345 is the factory default pin for both devices it appears.

Comment: We have multiple Bluetooth access points, and we want to have each access point have a mac address filter for devices that it can connect to.

Comment: Could one solution be the this? The pirani ap Bluetooth mac address filter on each device be changed by software or changing a file saved on its system. Have 2 access points with the default authentication pin set to 333, and if we want the scanner to connect to a certain access point, add an entry on the access points mac filter and set the filters pin to 12345 for that individual scanner.